# Which image editor can be used within Drupal for creating flowcharts?

Tags: media

I am looking for an image editor within Drupal. Particularly, I need something that will help me create flowcharts and save them directly.

The idea is to avoid using an offline image editor, to make the site more user-friendly.

Any pointers?

Comment: Have you investigated the https://drupal.org/project/imageeditor module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Image Editor module](https://drupal.org/project/imageeditor)

> integrates several popular online image editing services into Drupal:

There are integrations with quite a few popular online image editing services.